# Check that a String entered contains only 1's and 0's

Tags: java

I am writing a program that switches a binary number into a decimal number and am only a novice programmer. I am stuck trying to determine that the string that was entered is a binary number, meaning it contains only 1's and 0's. My code so far is:

```
  String num;
  char n;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a binary number or enter 'quit' to quit: ");
  num = in.nextLine();
  n = num.charAt(0);
  if (num.equals("quit")){
    System.out.println("You chose to exit the program.");
    return;
  }

  if (n != 1 || n != 0){
    System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number.");
  }
```

As is, no matter what is entered (other then quit) the program out-puts "You did not enter a binary number" even when a binary number is inputted. I am sure my if statement is false or my character declaration is wrong, however I have tried everything I personally know to correct the issue and nothing I find online helps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, n is a character. The character "0" is different from the integer 0. So (n != 0) will always be true.

Comment: corrected n to type int, much appreciated

Comment: Despite the fact that the OP's attempt to solve contains a simple mistake, the question itself (and its top answer) are still generally useful to a large number of people. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 20):

You could just use a regular expression:

```
num.matches("[01]+")
```

This will be `true` if the string `num` contains only `0` and `1` characters, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Just as a note, this will return false for an empty string. Whether or not an empty string is a valid binary number is up to the implementation =P

Comment: False, this matches if there is at least one 0 or 1.  If you ONLY want numbers you will use "^[01]+$"

Comment: @Suroot I don't think so, `"12".matches("[01]+")` returns `false`.

Comment: This was attempted in the if statement however no matter what was entered (binary or not) the statement returned false meaning the if statement was skipped if "54" was entered.

Comment: @A.R.S. I think this only works because of how Java regular expressions work (more specifically not assuming a partial match).  If you use the .find() it will not work this same way.

Comment: @user1701604: Did you use `if (! num.matches("[01]+")) { System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number"); }` ?

Comment: I think using regexp in this case is too complicated solution.

Comment: @Alexey Looping over the characters manually seems far more complicated to me, when you can have the same affect in just 1 line, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @A.R.S. I think regexp should be used to check more complex strings like email for example. And there is no loop in the program but just first element.

Comment: @Alexey - *"And there is no loop in the program but just first element."*.  Well it is wrong isn't it!  The title and text of the question clearly implies that he wants a solution that works for strings consisting of multiple characters as well.

Answer (score 2):

`n!=1 || n!=0` is always true because you cannot have n = 0 and 1 at the same moment.
I guess you wanted to write `n!=1 && n!=0`.