# I can't restrict my program to accept only binary numbers

Tags: java

I'm creating a program for my gui number converter. I want my program to ask user a binary string and if he does not enter a binary number, the program will show him error message and will ask him to enter again. The problem is that I can add restriction to alphabets but when it comes to numbers then it fails or it keeps showing the error message.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in;
    int b;
    public test(){
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the binary string of 5 numbers");
            in = key.nextLine();
            int i,j;
            char ch;
            for (i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++){
                b = 0;
                ch = in.charAt(i);
                j = ch;
                if (Character.isDigit(ch) && ch<=0 && ch>=1)
                    b = 1;
                else
                    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number (1 , 0)");
                break;
                //b = 1;
            }
        }while(b != 1);

        int c;
        c = Integer.parseInt(in);
        System.out.println("your number is: " + c );
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        test obj = new test();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809914/check-that-a-string-entered-contains-only-1s-and-0s).

Comment: @FredLarson i suppose this makes a huge difference :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ch<=0 && ch>=1` does not do what you think it does. The character codes for "0" and "1" are 48 and 49, so you should check for those instead. Also, your `>=` comparators are backwards, but that's not really the clearest way to write this code. And since you're comparing for just those two values, `Character.isDigit(ch)` is redundant.

Try one of these:

```
ch == 48 || ch == 49

ch == '0' || ch == '1'
```

Comment: could also be Character.isDigit(ch) && (ch == '0' || ch == '1')

Comment: I think the `Character.isDigit(ch)` check is entirely superfluous.

Comment: this worked sir! i was forgetting the single quotation mark.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` has an overloaded `nextInt` method that uses a radix

```
int binaryNumber = scanner.nextInt(2);
```

Comment: nice to mention that! for beginners a little bit challenching but plain and clean!

Comment: i'm not this advanced in java to use radix. still beginner, anyways thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1) First logic error here  `for (i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++)` replace  `i<=5` to `i<5`

2) change the if else condition like below

```
if (Character.isDigit(ch) && (ch == '0' || ch == '1'))
{
     b = 1;
}
else
{
     System.out.println("Please enter a binary number (1 , 0)");
     break;
}
```

Comment: Did you only add `{ }` in part 2) or am I missing something?

Comment: The if condition will still never match - '0' != 0